# Youtube video stutters

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, flash, youtube

I have an nvidia geforce 7400 graphics card with 1 GB of RAM. Just did a clean installation of 11.10 Ubuntu. Everything is fine except for the youtube videos, apart from being a lil slow it stutters, esp the audio. I Disactivated the "Hardware acceleration" in the flash properties and also installed Flash-Aid and tried to install the versions it was recommending. But the problem persists. Is it an nvidia problem? What could I do to resolve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew, Thanks for the reply. I just checked that out, it says that my browser doesnt support h.264. I joined the html5 trial. BTW i have firefox 11.0. The problem is still there, enabling html5 didnt help..

Comment: Installed chromiem But there also have the same problem. Its as if the computer is under too much load when the video is being played(Video and audio take small breaks) even though, everything seems normal. I believe its a flash problem, i had the same problme with Karmic Koala but Flash-Aid resolved it not this time though...

Comment: @Matthew, my problem is resolved! Try restarting your system after using Flash-Aid and youtube.com/html5, might help you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my problem is resolved after shutting my computer down and restarting it! Perhaps it needed a restart after changing versions in Flash-Aid and also the www.youtube.com/html5. Don't know exactly how it started working...